# Why does this code work in the console but not on page load?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to add a class to multiple divs of the same name, for some reason this code runs in the console but not when the page loads, any particular reason why?

Code below:

```
<div id="reply"></div>

<script>
var reply = document.querySelector('#reply');
for(i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
  reply[i].classList.add('dark');
}
</script>
```

Apologies there isn't much else I can explain, any help is appreciated!

Comment: IDs must be unique in a document.  Use classnames instead.

Comment: put js code after html code.

Comment: yeah, that too, and wrap it in a script tag if you aren't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The querySelector() method only returns the first element that matches the specified selectors. To return all the matches, use the querySelectorAll() method instead.

If the selector matches an ID in document that is used several times (Note that an "id" should be unique within a page and should not be used more than once), it returns the first matching element.

So use class instead of #id. Also wrap the the whole javascript code in

```
document.ready(function(){
    //put js code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over the result from a call to `document.querySelector` as that will return `0` or `1` **HTMLElements**.

To get an array-like result to iterate over, you need to call `document.querySelectorAll` which returns an **HTMLElementCollection**.

In your case you are targeting an element with a specific `id`. **Since there cannot be more than one element with any given `id` value**, `document.getElementById` would be the appropriate (and fastest) DOM API call. Like `document.querySelector`, it returns an **HTMLElement**.

So you have 4 solutions available:

### 1 Stick to document.querySelector

```
<div id="reply"></div>
<script>
var reply = document.querySelector('#reply'); // note that this line is optional
reply.classList.add('dark');
</script>
```

### 2 Use document.getElementById

```
<div id="reply"></div>
<script>
var reply = document.getElementById('reply'); // note that this line is optional
reply.classList.add('dark');
</script>
```

### 3 Use document.querySelectorAll

(which doesn't make much sense in the context of an id selector as reply.length will always be 0 or 1)

```
<div id="reply"></div>
<script>
var reply = document.querySelectorAll('#reply');
for(i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
  reply[i].classList.add('dark');
}
</script>
```

### 4 Use class instead of id (allowing for multiple occurrences of that `div`)

```
<div class="reply"></div>
<script>
var reply = document.querySelectorAll('.reply');
for(i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
  reply[i].classList.add('dark');
}
</script>
```

which can also be achieved using `document.getElementsByClassName`:

```
<div class="reply"></div>
<script>
var reply = document.getElementsByClassName('reply');
for(i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
  reply[i].classList.add('dark');
}
</script>
```